# Is there an AWS service for running scripts against an API & saving received data

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl

I am working in an AWS environment and I need to do the following [EDIT] as a daily scheduled task [/EDIT]:

1. Run python/http scripts to call an external (outside AWS) API multiple times.
2. Save the output of each call into a CSV
3. Dump the multiple CSVs into a Redshift database.

I looked at AWS Glue but I don't think I can do the first step in it. What workflow or combination of tools would you suggest?

Comment: How long does it take to execute the job? How large is the generated CSV file? This is to understand whether its possible to use a Lambda.

Comment: A few seconds for each api call. The generated csv files are not big... they are summaries really, a few hundred KB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use EC2 to hit the API and store the CSVs
2. Use the `boto3` library to upload these to S3
3. Use the `COPY` command to load the data from S3 into Redshift (by far the fastest way)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I neglected to mention that I want this to run as a daily scheduled job.... Won't I have to start/stop the instance every day?

Comment: No. You can use `cron` or `supervisor` to schedule your API downloading and `boto` calling script as a daily job, and it will run every day automatically without any intervention.

Comment: Also I should mention that you don't have to use `boto3` - this is just the Python AWS API - there are many others. But the overall logic is still the same for any one of these.  I use `boto3` for the EC2 -> S3 -> Redshift load daily.

Comment: I see, but cron and supervisor would be on the EC2 instance ... or my laptop. Is there a way to use AWS batch or some AWS based service to initiate/stop the scripts. I want to set it up to be as automated as possible and fully within the AWS ecosystem. Sorry, AWS beginner here!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Having RTFMed, I realize this is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [Lambda function with scheduled events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) to crawl the API.

Using Lambda most probably will be cheaper compared to provisioning an EC2 instance since your job is not time consuming and the data amount is less.

If you are hoping to use an EC2 instance still you can use the Lambda schedule event to [start and stop the EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/) (Or the EC2 instance itself can shutdown once the job is done).